# How to filter object and updated what is filtered? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, filter, filtering, updates

I want to filter object and update what is filtered as a result.

E.g:

```
// global object (parent)
let globalObj = {
    id: 123,
    name: "No Name",
    attributes: [{
        keyA: "Key",
        keyB: "Keys 2",
    }]
}
```

I have the above global parent object, which is the task to accept data and save it. (Like the store in Redux)

```
let updatedObj = {
    id: 123,
    name: "New Name",
    attributes: [{
        keyA: "New Key",
    }]
}
```

Well, now i want copare filter global object with new, filter it and update only what is changed, other must be untached..
As a result I want to get someting like this :

```
// global object (parent after update)
let globalObj = {
    id: 123,
    name: "New Name",
    attributes: [{
        keyA: "New Key",
        keyB: "Keys 2",
    }]
}
```

How I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `deep merge` package for this.

You can use [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) or `lodash` [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge)

If you know exactly what keys you want to update you could simply use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for **each individual level and key**. Object.assign does a shallow copy/merge.

For the first level, you can use Object.assign

```
let mergedObject = Object.assign({}, globalObj, updatedObj)
```

This will correctly merge top level keys, but attributes will be wrong. So you need to go one level down for this.

```
merged.attributes = globalObj.attributes.map( (item, index) => 
  Object.assign({}, item, updatedObj.attributes[i])
)
```

This will **only work** if the arrays have the same size. This is extremely important.

It is not straight forward what merging 2 arrays means. There are a lot of questions that make array merging non trivial:

- how to do you add a new item
- how do you identify matching elements, so you know what element to update
- do you make this decision based on index (like I did), or do you use another strategy

This relies heavily on how you uniquely identify an array element, and this in itself is non trivial.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to learn how I can do this manually without libraries :) 
Feel free to post full code here :)